# C# XMLDocument to DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset, xmldocument

I assume I have to do this via a DataSet, but it doesn't like my syntax.

I have an XMLDocument called "XmlDocument xmlAPDP".

I want it in a DataTable called "DataTable dtAPDP".

I also have a DataSet called "DataSet dsAPDP".

-

if I do DataSet dsAPDP.ReadXML(xmlAPDP) it doesn't like that because ReadXML wants a string, I assume a filename?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No hacks required:

```
xmlAPDP = new XmlDocument()
...
xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlAPDP)
dataSet = new DataSet()
...
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlReader)
```

XmlDocument is an XmlNode, and XmlNodeReader is a XmlReader, which ReadXml accepts.

Comment: Matthew : dont forget to close you XmlReader, or better use "using": `using (XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlAPDP.documentElement))
{ dsAPDP.ReadXml(reader); reader.Close();
}
dtAPDP = dsAPDP.tables[0];`

Answer (score 3):

ASP.net example:

```
private DataTable GetReportDataTable()
{
    //get mapped path to xml document
    string xmlDocString = Server.MapPath("CustomReports.xml");

    //read into dataset
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlDocString);

    //return single table inside of dataset
    return dataSet.Tables[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
dsAPDP.ReadXml(new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlAPDP.OuterXml)))
```